# How can I make IE11 to show me the URL of the links am hovering over?

Tags: internet-explorer, url, user-interface, links

How can I make IE 11 to show me the URL of the links I am hovering over? The problem is that it **sometimes** shows these links as a tooltip popup framelet below, and **sometimes** - does not. I never see anything in the status bar.

I have a page where some links work and some does not. What is interesting, on the other page of the same site, with several same links, they behave differently. Their behaviour is stable for the concrete page and link on it.

That behaviour can be found on this site, too - ask a question and try "Answer Your Question" button. All other buttons and links are OK.

The Chrome does show links on the same pages correctly.

Comment: reference - link. Sorry, I am too old-fashioned, have started to program 13 years before Internet. Thank you for your questions, I have edited my post answering them.

Comment: what do you mean with "tooltip popup framelet"? IE shows the url in the status bar, if that is visible.

Comment: @ths Mine does not. How can I make it to do it? As for the tooltip, I turned it on by "show notification bar" in Advanced Options.

Comment: @Dave Sorry, they are pages for electronical banking. But here, on SO, all links and buttons are OK, except "Answer your Question" button.

Comment: @Dave Try  "ask a question " here and "Answer your Question" button on the page.

Comment: @Dave Then edit your old question

Comment: @Dave According to ths, you all se the URLs in the status bar. I - don't. How to turn it on there?

Comment: Right, I've made a question and I can see `Answer your question`. This does not show the URL in Chrome or IE for me... but then it won't, it's a button, not a hyper link. And buttons (HTML elements) can be made to look the same as standard `a href` links... This may be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303102/how-to-disable-defalut-url-showing-when-overing-on-button

Comment: @Dave But "Save edit" button shows it OK.

Comment: @Gangnus, I have a different experience to you but mine is consistent. For buttons, in Chrome, I do not see any preview of the URL at all (such as `save edit`). However, if I hover over your name, I can see the URL

Comment: @Dave In my IE the link "automatically move this discussion to chat?" does not show anything, too.

Comment: @Dave My Chrome does not show URLs for buttons, too, as I see... But IE does - for some of them.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions It seems, we have tried the laws of the Universe too much :-( I don't see the invitation to the chat anymore, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64055/discussion-between-dave-and-gangnus).

Comment: ah,i see, ie shows the url as a tooltip instead of in the status bar if the status bar is disabled. the "show encoded..." option is under "international options" so it's only about specific urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on these 2 links taken from the a comment in the OP, the blue and red as per the screen shot:

[image]

If I inspect the element in the dev tools of my name (shown in red) I can see

```
<a href="/users/146314/dave" title="22,028 reputation" class="comment-user">Dave</a>
```

If I do the same with edit, I can see

```
<a class="comment-edit">edit</a>
```

Note for edit, there is no `href`

If I hover over a comment I left, I see a little circle with an x in, which provides me a way to delete a comment. In this case there is no URL preview and again the tag 
`<a class="comment-delete delete-tag" title="delete this comment"></a>` has no `href`

I suspect that the Chrome is doing some additional calculations to work out what the destination URL is (if it can), where as IE is relying on the href attribute to be filled in (and it still ignores where only `#` is used in the `href`, as per the delete and flag links in each post).

IE plug-in support is blugh, but I would think this is the only way you can achieve this, without using another browser.

So using the above and the following (in yellow as an example):

[image]

In Chrome, the following provided a URL:

My name in a comment
The edit comment, 
share post, 
edit post, 
delete post 
flag post.

The delete comment did not show a URL

In IE, only my name in the comment, and the option to share post and edit post (shown in yellow above) show the URL when I hover the mouse over

As for the status bar (if it's on or not in IE), to turn the status bar on... In IE, press ALT on your keyboard to show the menu, then go to View -> Toolbars and make sure Status View has a check (tick). Even without the status bar, a pop up should still be displayed

Comment: Thank you, +1. And please, do you see the URL in the status bar?

Comment: @Gangnus, I used my name in a comment, the edit comment, delete comment, share post, edit post, delete post and flag post. In Chrome, all but the delete comment showed the URL. In IE, only my name in comment, share post and edit post show the URL

Comment: In STATUS BAR or in some other place? Please!

Comment: Define status bar. If you mean the greyish bar at the bottom of IE with the zoom option then yes, I am talking about that...

Comment: In Chrome I see Url in  the long narrow stripe that goes along the lower border of browser window - status bar. In IE I see no status bar at all.

Comment: Turn the status bar on... In IE, press `ALT` on your keyboard to show the menu, then go to `View` -> `Toolbars` and make sure `Status View` has a check (tick). Even without the status bar, a pop up should still be displayed

Comment: Thank you. But alas - It did not help. I see or do not see URLs the same with or without status bar. I don't think we can get more from the theme :-(

Comment: Also see http://help.isu.edu/index.php?action=knowledgebase&catid=38&subcatid=64&docid=598 @Gangnus

Comment: It seems, IE does not want to show href containing javascripts - that is my problem.

Comment: I have seen the page and already fulfilled that about 3 hors ago :-). Thanks.